# karate: File upload using csv file

Tags: karate

am trying to implement testing for POST request  to upload file using csv file format.But getting response as 500 exception.

```
Given path  location + 'abc/ssd?&id=22'
And multipart file myFile = { read: 'test.csv', filename: 'test.csv', ContentType: 'text/csv' }
When method post
Then status 200


Response : 
Content-Type : multipart/form-data; boundary=jyrjg5ysdfdgj4gdgsjm2342
```

Comment: HTTP status 500 is Internal Server Error. So, it has to do with something that does not work in server. Your karate code/calls seem to be okay.

Comment: Sorry.. it worked fine..I gave wrong multipart name.thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to figure with the lack of details.

Anyway, note that it should be `contentType` with a lower-case `c`.

If you still have problems, try providing more info.

Comment: Karate API really helpful.. Thanks for all your hard work it is much appreciated...